# How to add a custom price attribute for RRP?

Tags: magento2, price

In Magento 2 CE, I'm trying to add a product attribute called "RRP" (Recommended Retail Price) and display it on the frontend product page near the other prices. (Existing MSRP function isn't appropriate because we don't use MAP.)

I'd like to use the proper price rendering functionality rather than fudging it by sticking a hard-coded currency sign in front of a raw but rounded decimal value from the attribute.

I'm following the [pricing library docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/behavior/pricing.html) but they're not very detailed.

My module, called "RRP", includes a new attribute, set up below in `app/code/Acme/RRP/Setup/InstallData.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\RRP\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $eavSetup;
    public function __construct(EavSetup $eavSetup)
    {
        $this->eavSetup = $eavSetup;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->eavSetup->addAttribute("catalog_product", "rrp", [
            'type'          => 'decimal',
            'backend'       => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price',
            'label'         => 'RRP',
            'input'         => 'price',
            'required'      => false,
            'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            'group'         => 'General'
        ]);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I've tried to set up a custom price type by creating a new class that extends `Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPrice`. It lives at `app/code/Acme/RRP/Pricing/Price/RRPPrice.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\AbstractPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\BasePriceProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class RRPPrice
 */
class RRPPrice extends AbstractPrice
{
    /**
     * Price type
     */
    const PRICE_CODE = 'rrp_price';

    /**
     * Get price value
     *
     * @return float|bool
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        if ($this->value === null) {
            $price = $this->product->getRrp();
            $priceInCurrentCurrency = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndRound($price);
            $this->value = $priceInCurrentCurrency ? floatval($priceInCurrentCurrency) : false;
        }
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

And I think I need to configure the DI at `app/code/Acme/RRP/etc/di.xml`, although I'm not sure if I've done this correctly (since I've re-declared those included in the `di.xml` for the core Magento_Catalog):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\Pool" type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rrp_price" xsi:type="string">Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\RRPPrice</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="target" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Pool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="pool" xsi:type="object">Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\Pool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

I've declared the template for the `rrp_price` price type in `app/code/Acme/RRP/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml` (again, not sure if this is correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="rrp_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Acme_RRP::product/price/rrp_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

I created a template for the RRP price at `app/code/Acme/RRP/view/base/templates/product/price/rrp_price.phtml`:

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-'),
    'include_container' => true
]);
?>
```

Finally, I override the `final_price.phtml` template to include a call to render the new RRP price. This lives at `app/design/frontend/Acme/[mytheme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`:

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

$productId = $block->getSaleableItem()->getId();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');

/** @var \Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\RRPPrice $rrpPriceModel */
$rrpPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('rrp_price');

$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>

<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($rrpPriceModel->getAmount(), [
    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('rrp-price-' . $idSuffix),
    'price_type'        => 'rrpPrice',
    'include_container' => true,
    'schema'            => $schema
]); ?>

<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmountMinimal(); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I re-run the compile, clear caches and so on, and then refresh the product page, I get the following:

```
Class  does not exist
#0 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('')
#1 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('')
#2 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('')
#3 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('', Array)
#4 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/Factory.php(47): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create(NULL, Array)
#5 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Price/Collection.php(137): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Factory->create(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), NULL, NULL)
#6 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceInfo/Base.php(61): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Collection->get('rrp_price')
#7 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php(111): Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceInfo\Base->getPrice('rrp_price')
#8 /[mypath]/app/design/frontend/Acme/[themename]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml(23): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox->getPriceType('rrp_price')
#9 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/Users/[username]...')
#10 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Decorator/DebugHints.php(42): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox), '/Users/[username]...', Array)
#11 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Developer\Model\TemplateEngine\Decorator\DebugHints->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox), '/Users/[username]...', Array)
#12 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/Users/[username]...')
#13 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render/PriceBox.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php(31): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox->_toHtml()
#15 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->_toHtml()
#16 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/Render.php(99): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#17 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render.php(58): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render->render('final_price', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#18 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(657): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render->_toHtml()
#19 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#20 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.price.f...')
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.price.f...')
#22 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#24 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.price.f...')
#25 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.price.f...', true)
#26 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.price.f...')
#27 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('product.info.pr...')
#28 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.pr...')
#29 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#31 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.pr...')
#32 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.pr...', true)
#33 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.pr...')
#34 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('product.info.bu...')
#35 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.bu...')
#36 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#37 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#38 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.bu...')
#39 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.bu...', true)
#40 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.bu...')
#41 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('product.info.ma...')
#42 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#43 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#44 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#45 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.ma...')
#46 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.ma...', true)
#47 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('product.info.ma...')
#48 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#49 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#50 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#51 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#52 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#53 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#54 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#55 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#56 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#57 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#58 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#59 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#60 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#61 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#62 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#63 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#64 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#65 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#66 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#67 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#68 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#69 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#70 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#71 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#72 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#73 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#74 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#75 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#76 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#77 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#78 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#79 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#80 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#81 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#82 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#83 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#84 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#85 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#86 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderNonCached...', Array, Array)
#87 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#88 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#89 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#90 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#91 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#92 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#93 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#94 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#95 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#96 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#97 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#98 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#99 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#100 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#101 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#102 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#103 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#104 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#105 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(141): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#106 /[mypath]/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#107 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#108 /[mypath]/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#109 /[mypath]/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#110 {main}
```

Clearly, the configuration is wrong in one or more places?

Comment: I have the same requirement. Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @DarrenSutherland The project was abandoned, so I didn't get any further with this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

There are some minor problems in your XML Files.

> app/code/Acme/RRP/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml

You are overriding the **render.product.prices** block. Instead you have to reference the block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="rrp_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Acme_RRP::product/price/rrp_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

> app/code/Acme/RRP/etc/di.xml

The virtualType of the collection isn't needed. You just need to update the price type pool with your new type:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rrp_price" xsi:type="string">Acme\RRP\Pricing\Price\RRPPrice</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: For me it didn't work if I added the virtualType in etc/frontend/di.xml, it works only in etc/di.xml as mentioned by @gion-koch. Something to keep in mind if it still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command once you've done the changes pointed out by @Gion Koch if you still see the `Class does not exist` error message.