# Magento 2.3.3 - Change price in catalog product view

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, layout, attributes

I want to change the price in the Catalog View Page, I use a price attribute with the name rrp, and I need when customers are logged to display this price attribute otherwise display the normal price. I do this in Category Page like this:

```
                <?php
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
                if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="price-box">
                        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php $_product->getId() ?>">
                            <span class="price">
                                <?php $pricingHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data::class); ?>
                                <?php echo $pricingHelper->currency($_product->getData('rrp'), true, false); ?>
                            </span> 
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

But how I can do the same for Product View?

Thank you

Comment: What price should be when product will be added to cart ? Is this for display purpose only ?

Comment: @AnilSuthar in the cart must be the correct price, for example if the customer is logged then in the Cart will be the rrp price, otherwise the normal price.

Comment: Is that code done to change price based on logged in and guest customers ? From the code you posted will just show the price but wont change it upon adding to cart

Comment: @AnilSuthar sorry but I don't understand very well, but for product list the code work fine, I need to do the same in the Product View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a plugin that changes the price after product loaded.

**1 >** Create `di.xml` file :

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product_price" type="VENDOR_NAME\MODULE_NAME\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2 >** Change the product price :

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR_NAME\MODULE_NAME\Plugin;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        // Create your logic here to change product price and return it
        return $result + 100;
    }
}
```

**3 >** Flush Cache and Test

For more check [How to change product price](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-change-product-price-with-plugin-magento-2.html)

---

Your logic should be (Just for demo. *Not Tested and don't use ObjectManager directly, use dependency instead.*) :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    return $subject->getData('rrp');
}else{
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help but can you give us an example with logic too?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I think I found something here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122995/how-to-add-a-custom-price-attribute-for-rrp